# Wait untill nested functions complete to continue next .each()

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make my `.each()` wait until all nested functions are completed?

Heres my code

**HTML:**

```
<div>
   <p>Text 1</p>
   <p>Text 2</p>
   <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function function1(){
  $.get(getURL, function(data) {
           if(data == "false"){
               PostLog("ERROR: Could not get Product Number or Description", "error");`//PostLog adds new line to on page log`
           }else if(data == "true"){
               PostLog("Retrieved Product Number and Description", "proccess");
               PostLog("Completed Crawl", "success");
           }
        });

}

function function2(){
  //do some stuff
}


$('p').each(function()
    {

    function1();
    function2();

});
```

Basically I would like functions 1 & 2 for Text 1, once functions complete then functions 1 & 2 for Text 2...

if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

**EDIT**

Sorry i forgot to mention a few details..

In function 1 it calls an external php script and takes about 30secs for functions 1 to return true. But by the time function 2 has returned the next `each()` has been run.

Comment: Have you even tried it? [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/7d02aad1/) Or do you have a specific problem with your code?

Comment: Or are your processing `ajax`-calls inside your functions?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `callbacks`.

```js
function function1(control,callback) {
  console.log("Executing Function 1 for "+control.text());
  callback(control);//call the 2nd function here
}

function function2(control) {
  console.log("Executing Function 2 for "+control.text());
}


$('p').each(function() {
  function1($(this),function2); //pass the callback function
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <p>Text 1</p>
   <p>Text 2</p>
   <p>Text 3</p>
</div>
```

**Update**

There wouldn't be much change but just move `callback function` within `get` as below:

```
function function1(control,callback) {
     $.get(getURL, function(data) {
           if(data == "false"){
               PostLog("ERROR: Could not get Product Number or Description", "error");`//PostLog adds new line to on page log`
           }else if(data == "true"){
               PostLog("Retrieved Product Number and Description", "proccess");
               PostLog("Completed Crawl", "success");
           }
           callback(control); //call it here now.
      });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, i have tried what you suggested but still have the same problem. please see edited question for more details.

Comment: Could you add how you have called `php` function?

Comment: Added php script call @Guruprasad

Comment: This only ensure that function 2 is executed after function 1, for each `p`. But maybe not in `p` order... for example, if the 2nd `get()` takes longer than the 3rd., the output would be functions executed on `TEXT1, TEXT3, TEXT2`. OP wanted `.each()` to wait... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not a jquery question per se, but in your case, you can just pass the element as a parameter to each of the functions:

```
function f1(el) { 
    // do things with/for el
}

function f2(el) {
    // do things with/for el
}

// getting all the elements we want
var $elements = $("p");

// iterating over each element in the pseudo-array and passing it to the functions
$elements.each(function(i, el) {
    f1(el);
    f2(el);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the `.get()` function take random time to execute...

I *reproduced* this random time with a random setTimeout.
This is only for the example.

jQuery `.each()` will not *wait*. It will only trow the function calls.

What I explain here, is how to make a "custom each" function.

This function, which I called `doItInOrder()`, "processes" `p`s one by one by calling function 1.
Function 1 calls function 2.
And finally function 2 recalls our "custom each" function to loop again.

To call the next function, you'll have to use the `success` callback of the `.get()` function. [Reference here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).

See [my Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/2pgm5b5p/)

```
// Check how many p you have
var Plength = $('p').length;
$("#console").append(Plength+" 'p' elements<br><br>");


j=0;
function doItInOrder(){
    // Call function 1 if all p have been "processed"
    if( j < Plength ){
        function1();
    }
}

// Simulated get function with random time
function function1(){

    var thisRandomTime = getRandom();
    $("#console").append(thisRandomTime+" milliseconds later:<br>");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#console").append("Did function 1 on "+$("p").eq(j).html()+"<br><br>");

        function2();

    },thisRandomTime);
}

// Simulated get function with random time
function function2(){

    var thisRandomTime = getRandom();
    $("#console").append(thisRandomTime+" milliseconds later...<br>");

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#console").append("Did function 2 on "+$("p").eq(j).html()+"<br><br>");

        // Call for next iteration
        j++
        doItInOrder();

    },thisRandomTime);
}

// Calls the first iteration
doItInOrder();

// Used to simulate random execution time in this example
function getRandom() {
    return (Math.random()*1000).toFixed(2);
}
```

**----**
**Starting from your code now:**
It would look like this:

```
// Check how many p you have
var Plength = $('p').length;


var j=0;
function doItInOrder(){
    // Call function 1 if all p have been "processed"
    if( j < Plength ){
        function1();
    }
}

function function1(){
  $.get(getURL, function(data) {
           if(data == "false"){
               PostLog("ERROR: Could not get Product Number or Description", "error");`//PostLog adds new line to on page log`
           }else if(data == "true"){
               PostLog("Retrieved Product Number and Description", "proccess");
               PostLog("Completed Crawl", "success");

               // then:
               function2();
           }
        });

}

function function2(){
  //do some stuff using `$("p").eq(j)` to target the element.
  PostLog( "Working on "+$("p").eq(j).html() );

  // then:
  j++;
  doItInOrder();
}

// first iteration call
doItInOrder();
```